# Unable to pip install in Docker image as agent through Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, pip

I have *yet another* issue with permissions running Docker through Jenkins declarative pipeline. I want to build and publish a Python package through a Jenkins job in a Docker container:

```
pipeline {

  agent {
    docker {
      image 'python:3.7'
      label 'docker && linux'
    }
  }

  environment {
    PACKAGE_VERSION = readFile 'VERSION'
  }

  stages {

    stage('Package') {
      steps {
        sh 'python -V'
        sh 'python -m pip install -r requirements.txt --user --no-cache'
        sh 'python setup.py sdist'
      }
    }

    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        ...
      }
    }

  }

  post {
    always {
      cleanWs()
    }
  }

}
```

**However, I am not allowed to `pip install` due to a `PermissionError`:**

> +python -m pip install -r requirements.txt --user --no-cache Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line
>   1)) (40.0.0) Collecting pytest (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
>   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/a1/8166a56ce9d89fdd9efcae5601e71758029d90e5644e0b7b6eda07e67c35/pytest-3.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (202kB) Collecting py>=1.5.0 (from pytest->-r requirements.txt (line
>   2))   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/bd/83369ff2dee18f22f27d16b78dd651e8939825af5f8b0b83c38729069962/py-1.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (83kB) Collecting more-itertools>=4.0.0 (from pytest->-r
>   requirements.txt (line 2))   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/b1/eace304ef66bd7d3d8b2f78cc374b73ca03bc53664d78151e9df3b3996cc/more_itertools-4.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
>   (48kB) Collecting pluggy>=0.7 (from pytest->-r requirements.txt (line
>   2))   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/f1/5a93c118663896d83f7bcbfb7f657ce1d0c0d617e6b4a443a53abcc658ca/pluggy-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from pytest->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
>   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting atomicwrites>=1.0 (from pytest->-r requirements.txt (line
>   2))   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0a/e8/cd6375e7a59664eeea9e1c77a766eeac0fc3083bb958c2b41ec46b95f29c/atomicwrites-1.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Collecting attrs>=17.4.0 (from pytest->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
>   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/59/cedf87e91ed541be7957c501a92102f9cc6363c623a7666d69d51c78ac5b/attrs-18.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   Installing collected packages: py, six, more-itertools, pluggy,
>   atomicwrites, attrs, pytest
>
> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local' 
>   Check the permissions.

How do I fix these permissions?

Comment: Do not use `--user` since it looks like you're already root in the container. `--user` is for unprivileged installs.

Comment: If I install without `--user` I obtain: 

Installing collected packages: six, more-itertools, py, atomicwrites, pluggy, attrs, pytest
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Hmm, then you're not root in the container as it seems. Something's not right with the user in the container. I recall Jenkins starting the containers with `jenkins` user by default; can you confirm that? Add `sh 'id -a'` to `steps`, what user is printed? Maybe the default uid/gid set by Jenkins is borked.

Comment: You can of course run the agent as root by adding `args '--user 0:0'` to the `docker` declaration, but it would be interesting to figure out what's wrong with the default setup and `pip install`ing with `--user` flag.

Comment: Jenkins added `-u 1001:1001` and it's true that overruling this with `-u 0:0` solves the issue. But then it doesn't make sense to me that `pip install ... --user` does not work. Could permissions in the docker image be faulty set up?

Comment: Yeah, it kinda makes sense. The problem is that the `python:3.7` image knows nothing about the user with ID 1001 - if you run `cat /etc/passwd | grep 1001` inside the container, nothing will be found. Jenkins starts the container as a user that does not exist, no entry in `passwd`, no home dir etc. I assume that `HOME` is left to `/` in that case, so `pip install --user` resorts to installing to `/.local` which 1. doesn't exist and if it would 2. would belong to root anyway.

Comment: I guess you have to either run the container as root (yuck! however, depends on what the container is used for - if it's disposed after build, it _may_ be harmless to run it as root), or write your own Dockerfile inheriting from `python:3.7` that adds a proper non-root user. Then pass this user to docker agent in Jenkinsfile.

Comment: @hoefling I've used the --user 0:0 args and it did work, but then I get a an issue running the pipeline again, so did you manage to work it out?

Comment: @tiagosilva If you are getting a different error, it's best to ask another question.

Comment: @hoefling [I did.. its not getting much traction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812697/how-to-pip-install-in-a-docker-image-with-a-jenkins-pipline-step) My issue is I can't run it as root, since the next jenkins build can't delete the root created files. So do you know how to add that non-root user and pass it to the docker agent?

Comment: @tiagosilva added an answer to your question. Basically, it's [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648534/unable-to-pip-install-in-docker-image-as-agent-through-jenkins-declarative-pipel?noredirect=1#comment90322558_51648534) from above, with an example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found what I myself would think is the prettier solution:

```
stage("Python Test") {
  agent { 
    docker {
      label "docker && linux" 
      image "python:3.7"
    }
  }
  steps {
    withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
      sh "pip install -r requirements.txt --user"
      # python stuff
    }
  }
  post {
    cleanup {
      cleanWs()
    }
  }
}
```

This workaround steers completely around the issue itself, installing the packages at user level. The issue here was that the HOME-directory was not initially writeable either, thus overwriting the HOME directory.

Comment: I'm confused about this answer.  In the question, it shows that `--user` is already being used, meaning that the packages were already being installed at the user level.  Then what was the source of the permission error?

Comment: @cowlinator `withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"])` is the difference. The user inside the container is not root, but also doesn't exist inside the container, so it gets set to a working directory of `/`.

Comment: `withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {} ` is the key. Also, it can be used like:
```
node {
    def customImage = docker.build(...)
    customImage.inside {
        withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
            sh '...'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606352/pip-install-not-working-with-jenkins?rq=3

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar pipeline that I was running right after setting up Docker agents on my Jenkins system, so I thought my setup was wrong. Using the comments in your thread, I cooked up this solution:

First, you'll need to be root inside your container, so change your agent declaration to be similar to this:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image "python:3.7"
        args '--user 0:0'
    }
}
```

Now I was able to use `pip install`! However, subsequent runs of the job would try to run `git clean` and fail since the built files inside the container were created by root. To fix that, I ran the clean command inside the container as my last step:

```
steps {
    sh 'git clean -fdx'
}
```

**Update:**

I found a problem where a failed build wouldn't clean up and killed all of the builds after it. To fix this, I put the clean action as a [post-build task](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) that always runs:

```
post {
    cleanup {
        cleanWs()
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly in combination with `post {
    cleanup {
      cleanWs()
    }
  }` as suggested @casparjespersen

Answer (score 0):

`withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {}`  is the key. Also, it can be used like:

```
node {
    def customImage = docker.build(...)
    customImage.inside {
        withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
            sh '...'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606352/pip-install-not-working-with-jenkins?rq=3

Answer (score -1):

You can try executing it as sudo:

```
 stage('Package') {
      steps {
        sh '''
            python -V
            sudo python -m pip install -r requirements.txt --user --no-cache
            sudo python setup.py sdist
           '''
      }
    }
```

You may have issues due Jenkins is not able to run command as `sudo` in that case I will recommend you to follow the steps mentioned in [this article](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/11/16/jenkins-running-steps-as-sudo) or in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940612/authentication-error-in-jenkins-on-using-sudo)

Comment: I don't think `sudo` will bring anything since it looks like the OP is alrrady root in the container.

Comment: I agree with @hoefling. Also, the Docker image based on python:3.7 does not have sudo installed :-)