# How to pip install in a docker image with a jenkins pipline step?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have this **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.7

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

and this **Jenkinsfile**:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile'
    }
}
stages {
    stage('Install') {
        steps {
            sh 'pip install --upgrade pip'
        }
    }
}
```

This causes the following error:

```
The directory '/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/f3/413bab4ff08e1fc4828dfc59996d721917df8e8583ea85385d51125dceff/pip-19.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.2
Uninstalling pip-19.0.2:
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] 
Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I have tried to user the `--user`, with no success.

I had some luck using args `--user 0:0` on the docker jenkinsfile declaration, but this creates directories and files owned by root which can not be deleted by the user Jenkins at the next run.

I don't want to do the `pip install` on the Dockerfile since in reality the Install step is running a make file instead of the simplification I used above, that I want to use in other contexts.

I've also seen advice to change the `HOME environment var`, and this seems to fix the first 2 warnings about the parent directoy not being owned by current user, but not the `Errno 13` part.

Comment: Why not do this in the image creation prior to its use as the Jenkins agent? That would be best practices around this and solve your problem.

Comment: @MattSchuchard As i mentioned I don't want to do the pip install on the Dockerfile since in reality the Install step is running a make file instead of the simplification I used above, that I want to use in other contexts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648534/unable-to-pip-install-in-docker-image-as-agent-through-jenkins-declarative-pipel?noredirect=1#comment90322558_51648534), the solution should be adding a proper user inside the container. Jenkins uses `984:984` for uid/gid on my machine (but may be different on yours - login to the host Jenkins is running on and execute `sudo -u jenkins id -a` to detect them), so you need to replicate it in the container that should be run by Jenkins:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN mkdir /home/jenkins
RUN groupadd -g 984 jenkins
RUN useradd -r -u 984 -g jenkins -d /home/jenkins jenkins
RUN chown jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins
USER jenkins
WORKDIR /home/jenkins

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Of course, since you aren't the `root` user in the container anymore, either create a virtual environment:

```
$ docker run --rm -it jenkins/python /bin/bash
jenkins@d0dc87c39810:~$ python -m venv myenv
jenkins@d0dc87c39810:~$ source myenv/bin/activate
jenkins@d0dc87c39810:~$ pip install numpy
```

or use the `--user` argument:

```
$ docker run --rm -it jenkins/python /bin/bash
jenkins@d0dc87c39810:~$ pip install --user --upgrade pip
jenkins@d0dc87c39810:~$ pip install --user numpy
```

etc.

---

Alternatively, you *can* (but in most cases shouldn't) enter the container as `root`, but with `jenkins` group:

```
$ docker run --user 0:984 ...
```

This way, although the modified files will still change the owner, their group ownership will still be intact, so Jenkins will be able to clean up the files (or you can do it yourself, via

```
sh 'rm -f modified_file'
```

in the `Jenkinsfile`.

Comment: didn't work. When running the `dockerfile with args '--user jenkins:jenkins'` this happens:  

`[Pipeline] sh
sh: 1: cannot create /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/template.test4@tmp/durable-07c23aa9/jenkins-log.txt: Permission denied
sh: 1: cannot create /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/template.test4@tmp/durable-07c23aa9/jenkins-result.txt.tmp: Permission denied`

these are just the 1st 2 errors, lots of similar ones forever, had to abort.

without the --user args, it continues to have no permission

Comment: I checked on my CentOS/Fedora hosts, seems like Jenkins has `984:984` for uid/gid. Check the update in the answer with a command to check them on yours.

Answer (score 2):

Using standard python:3.8 image

```
stage('Unit test') {
    steps {
        sh '''
            python -m venv .venv
            . .venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements.txt
            pytest -v
        '''
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, pip tries to use root directory.
We need to set HOME environment variable.

```
pipeline {
agent {
    dockerfile {
        filename 'Dockerfile'
    }
}

   // ******* Required change
    environment {
        HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}"
    }
   // ******* 

stages {
    stage('Install') {
        steps {
            sh 'pip install --upgrade pip'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a dynamic solution for this problem by creating a defined user in the Docker container using pipeline environment variables, *dynamically*. You can find the template for the **Jenkinsfile** and **Dockerfile** on my [GitHub](https://github.com/wmarcuse/jenkins-dynamic-user-dockerfile).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like issue is more related to users. As you docker agent is running with root user and you stage cmd is running with respective user configured in Jenkins(is root?).

Create a similar user in your docker file and assign the container running to that user.

Dockerfile

```
   FROM python:3.7

   ARG Jenkins_user=XXXXXX

   RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash $Jenkins_user

   USER $Jenkins_user

   CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Edited: Here Jenkins_user will be with which pip cmd is running in container. To check user you can put

sh 'echo $USER'

In install stage section. And then update Dokerfile with exact user.